# What is the hidden achievement in Pink Pointer's Sudoku game?

Tags: achievements, sudoku

In Pink Pointer's *Sudoku* game, there are 9 Google Play achievements, one of which is hidden. I have gotten all the achievements except for the hidden achievement. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how to unlock the hidden achievement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use any kind of tip or hint and that will do.

Comment: Do you mean that the achievement is unlocked by using a hint?